# React Native (Android) Deep Linking Issue with https url

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

i'm setting up deep linking in react native android app using http url. and when i try to open app from browser but it not open.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="https"
              android:host="www.abc.com"  />
      </intent-filter>
```

i expect app should be open.

Comment: did you get the answer for this? I'm getting same issue in both Android and IOS

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support both http and https, you can try this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="www.abc.com" />
</intent-filter>
```